# How to find string contain only alphabets in sas

Tags: sas

I need to find whether the string is numeric , character or alphanumeric in SAS

| String | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | Character |
| ABC123 | AlphaNum |
| 1234 | Numeric |

I tried PRXmatch but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input String $;
datalines;
ABC    
ABC123 
1234   
;

data want(drop = a n);
   set have;
   a = anyalpha(string);
   n = anydigit(string);

   if      a and n then     Remarks = 'Alphanum ';
   else if a and not n then Remarks = 'Character';
   else if n and not a then Remarks = 'Numeric  ';
run;
```

Result:

```
String  Remarks
ABC     Character
ABC123  Alphanum
1234    Numeric
```

Comment: ISALPHA don't work in sas ?

Comment: Use the anyalpha function.

Comment: Code is running smoothly , it works ...